# Android created a file in Android/data/com.mypackage but looks for it in data/data/com.mypackage

Tags: android, filenotfoundexception

This is how I create the file:

```
File directory = null;
    File file = null;

    try {

        directory = new File(this.getExternalFilesDir(null));
    } catch (Exception ex) {

        ex.printStackTrace();
        if (!directory.exists()) {
            directory.mkdirs();
        }
    }

    file = new File(directory, "user_data.json");

    if (!file.exists()) {
        try {

            file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and then this file appears in:

```
Android/data/com.mypackage.asd/files/user_data.json
```

but later on when I need it, using this code:

```
FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = context.openFileInput("user_data.json");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I get a NullPointerException and I see that the system looks for the file in

```
data/data/com.mypackage.asd/files/user_data.json
```

Why does it replace "Android" with "data" in the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, you are using `getExternalFilesDir()`.

In the second case, you are using `openFileInput()`.

Those are not pointing to the same place.

If you want your file to be placed onto [external storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), use `getExternalFilesDir()` **everywhere**.

If you want your file to be placed onto [internal storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), use `getFilesDir()` and/or `openFileInput()`.

Comment: so I should replace getExternalFilesDir() with getFilesDir()?

Comment: @J.Kowalski: That would depend on whether you want this file to be placed on internal storage or external storage.

Comment: ok I chose to use getExternalFilesDir() everywhere. how do I read the file this way?

Comment: @J.Kowalski: Use standard Java file I/O. You already have the code to get the `File`, so use `FileInputStream` or `FileReader` or whatever.